# Salesforce Data Service does not work: No COMPONENT named recordPreview found

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm building a Lightning Component for a record detail page. For this Lightning Component I need some data of the record itself. I found something really cool that fits my needs but can't seem to get it working because of a strange error.

I've used the Salesforce Data Service to load the data of the concurring record. Explained in the Developer Guide here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm

When I try to save the example I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named recordPreview found: Source

Did anyone else encountered this before and was able to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning Data Service is currently in Developer Preview, which means that you won't be able to use it in a Production or Sandbox org. You'll need a Developer Org to try it. You can get one [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000td6N).

This means that you won't be able to create a component for Production with Lightning Data Service in Winter '17.

Note that when I tried it was not enabled in my old Developer org, I had to create a new one to have LDS.